# find (and remove) common records between two tables (data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

I have two big tables with some fields in common (but having different field names). What would be the easiest/fastest way to find (and remove) such common records?

For example, I have

```
set.seed(2)
dt1 <- data.table(dt1field1=1:9,  dt1field2=LETTERS[runif(9,1,5)], dt1field3=letters[runif(9,12,15)])
dt2 <- data.table(dt2field1=1:10, dt2fieldB=LETTERS[runif(10,1,5)], dt2fieldC=letters[runif(10,12,15)])
```

<sub>(sorry for dumb filling)</sub>

What would be the `data.table` syntax to find all records where `t1field2=t2fieldB` AND `t1field3=t2fieldC`? (ok, if it is required, I can first rename fields to have equal names for the fields being compared)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works to have one table with only unique values:

```
setkeyv(dt1, names(dt1)[2:3])
setkeyv(dt2, names(dt2)[2:3])
dt2[dt1, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Otherwise, I think

```
dt2[!dt1, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Will work for each individual table.

Comment: thanks for an answer!
I changed an example a bit, and now it seems that your first code gives not only unique values, but all records from dt1 PLUS those records from dt2 which have same values...

Comment: That's a good point - I didn't realize that. You can stick with the second part of the answer, OR add `[!is.na(dtfield1)]` to the end.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines -

```
setkeyv(dt1,c('dt1field2','dt1field3'))
setkeyv(dt2,c('dt2fieldB','dt2fieldC'))
dt2[dt1, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

Comment: Messed the naming convention, fixed now.

Comment: You need `allow.cartesian` if the table is going to be longer than the longest of the two tables.

Comment: thank you both guys! (in my case the most useful was `dt2[!dt1` code of Señor O)